# 14hive corrupt?

Tags: isapi

We have two SP2010 installations, one single server with MSSQL2008R2 on the same machine, and another with MSSQL on a different machine. On both installations, we are able to create web apps and site collections, deploy them forth and back.
However, on both installations, I only see a BIN subdirectory in 
\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14

As far as my research shows, there should be all the good stuff I need for developement, especially the ISAPI folder and much more.

Any idea what is wrong?
Do I miss an SP 2010 installation step, do I have to activate something?

[edit] 
Thanks a lot for the answers! I am totally embarassed. Today, I've checked again and the expected subfolders are where they supposed to be. As it turns out, I have a \Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14 directory structure under C:\Program Files (x86) and under C:\Programs. The latter ist the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint will not work at all if there isn't more files in the 14hive.

You write:

> \Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14

The ordinary location is :

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14

But it can be changed before installation. To be sure you can run the following command in SharePoint 2010 Management Shell:

> [Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility]::GetGenericSetupPath("")

Comment: The SharePoint Root, should never, ever be changed!!!

Comment: No. @Wictor I agree, but if the files isn't in the right place it could be due to it having been changed. No code should ever assume that it hasen't been.

Answer (score 0):

If this does not work, I would strongly suggest you to run Repair installation for SharePoint 2010 from Control Panel->Programs & features, reinstall reporting service addin for SharePoint, and rerun the SharePoint 2010 products configuration wizard.